# Dynamically invoking a Void Method with a String name in C#

Tags: c#, string, dynamic, methods, invoke

my application is currently reading in a list of methods that I need to invoke, from the Database, and putting them into strings.

I want to be able to invoke these methods by their name, and pass parameters to them.

Heres a simple example of what I want to achieve:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          ...
          ...
          string MethodOne = "CombineText";
          string WordOne = "Hello";
          string WordTwo = "World";

          CombineText(WordOne, WordTwo);
      }

  public void CombineText(string WordOne, string WordTwo)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(WordOne+" "+WordTwo);
      }
```

I've seen plenty of examples online about invoking static methods, but I can't figure out how to invoke Public Void methods by name from strings.

Does anybody have any ideas? Much Appreciated!

Comment: In which part did you get stuck?

Comment: How do you know what class the method belongs to?  Will it always be the current type?  How do you know the signature of the method?  Will the string always contain a method with a fixed signature?  If not, how will you know what the parameters are, what types they should be, where to get them from, etc.  Also note that this pattern is code smell; you should really avoid the general concept of executing a string as code, there are usually preferable approaches.

Comment: Is a `switch` statement sufficient?  Does it *have* to be the name of the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx).

```
MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(MethodOne);
mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { WordOne, WordTwo };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `switch` instead of trying to call the method based on it's name.

```
switch(MethodOne)
{
   case "CombineText":
     CombineText(WordOne, WordTwo);
     break;
   default:
     Console.WriteLine("Invalid function: " + MethodOne);
     break;
}
```

This has the advantage of ensuring that you only accept valid arguments, and provides a way to sanitize the inputs on a per-function basis before evaluating (maybe you want to strip spaces from WordTwo for one function, for instance, or you want to pass the longer one in as the first parameter regardless of order.).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the method is an instance method of the current type:

```
MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod(MethodOne);
method.Invoke(this, new[] { WordOne, WordTwo });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at reflection. You need to do something like this:

```
Type type = GetType();
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(Method);
Method.Invoke(this, new object[] { WordOne, WordTwo });
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx